# Summation with certain condition

Tags: sql

I have the following table:-

[image]

I can get this:-

[image]

by using simple SQL:

```
Select Grade, sum(Qty) Qty, sum(Length) Length
from TableA
where
Serial like 'U4%'
```

but what I need is this:-

[image]

The Grade 2E is based on certain condition ie.15% allowance for excess Grade 2. The working is as follows:-

```
15% of Grade 1 => 15% x 305 = 46
Therefore, 2E is 190 (236-46).
```

I'm pretty new & need help on how can I do this split ?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to look into `between`, e.g. http://www.1keydata.com/de/sql/sql-between.php

Comment: Care to explain why and how to use 'between' for this particular example ?

Comment: Aren't your query missing a `GROUP BY`? What SQL product (and which version) is this for? Are there always just two grades? Are they always grade 1 and grade 2? Is allowance always calculated off grade 1 for grade 2/2E? Or is it always calculated off the grade with the greater `sum(Length)`? What have you tried yourself? Am I asking too many questions?

Comment: Nope, you are not. I'm using SQL Server 2008. In this example, 2 grades only but in reality, there are abt 5. For the allowance, it is always calculated off grade 1 with sum(length). So far, I can get the Grade 1 & 2, as above but not 2E. I do not know how to do split them.

Comment: So, to recap, you take Grade 1, calculate the allowance off it and go on to split each of the other however many grades into two using that allowance, right? Makes sense so far but I forgot to ask one other thing (sorry): should we worry about cases where the total length (of a grade being split) is exactly equal to or even less than the allowance? I mean, should the split actually take place, the E item being assigned a zero (or perhaps negative?) length? Would be great if you clarified that bit.

Comment: The calculation of allowance is limited to Grade 2 & 2E only. The rest are not affected. E can never be negative, at most assigned as 0. Let's use the above example. Instead of 236 (total length) of Grade 2, we assume it to be 30. So, if we split them now, Grade 2 will be 30 and Grade 2E will be zero.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select Grade, sum(Qty) Qty, sum(Length) Length
from TableA
where
Serial like 'U4%'

Unoin All

Select * from
(
Select Grade, null , sum(Length) - ((15/100) * sum(qty)) Length
from TableA
where
Serial like 'U4%'
) AS T
where grade=2
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Furthermore, it is not right to use " * sum(qty) ". It shd be based on length and not on qty. However, the length is based on Grade 1.